# Selecionar parte de uma string no sql (postgres)

Tags: sql, string, query

Faço estágio de análise de dados, e estou com a seguinte situação, preciso selecionar parte de uma string dentro da coluna, preciso de usuarioDestino: até o final do nome que está na coluna de observacao

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

preciso extrair apenas esse dado para alimentar uma outra coluna da tabela.

Comment: "*até o final do nome*", o que você classifica como "final do nome"? Todos os exemplos da imagem o nome é a última coisa na string, isso acontece em 100% dos casos ou há situações que há conteúdo após o nome? Se sim, como você pode identificar se uma palavra faz parte do nome da pessoa ou não?

Comment: Combine position e substring ....   https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-a-string-in-postgresql-mysql/

Comment: Nesse caso seria o final do nome do usuário destino, as vezes temos mais de uma ocorrência de ':' nos campos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando a função substring do sql.

A grande dificuldade está em selecionar onde está o ponto de corte da função substring.

Através dos dados que mostrou, estou supondo que a coluna *observacao*, possui pelo menos uma ocorrência do caractere <kbd>:</kbd>. Desta forma podemos montar uma consulta que resolve o seu problema.

Basicamente o que vai precisar é da função [position](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html) em conjunto com a função [substring](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html).

A função *position* retorna o índice da primeira ocorrência de uma string em outra string. Caso não encontre então ela retorna 0. Por isso é importante que exista pelo menos uma ocorrência do caractere `:`. Pois caso contrário a solução trará resultados indevidos.

Em nosso sql verifique que estou utilizando o índice do caractere `":"` + 1, estou fazendo isso para omitir o caractere espaço em branco que existe após o caractere ":".

Outra suposição que estou fazendo é a de que não existem outros caracteres após o nome do usuário, ou seja, estou supondo que a string termina no nome do usuário e não existe mais nenhuma string após o nome.

Segue um exemplo de como pode ser implementado:

```
SELECT id, observacao, substring(observacao, position(':' in observacao)+1) AS recorte FROM <nome-da-tabela>;
```

Neste exemplo acima estou mostrando o resultado da execução da função substring como sendo a coluna recorte.

### E se existem mais de uma ocorrência de ":"

Se a string possui o mesmo padrão, ou seja o nome que deseja está após a ultima ocorrência do ":" você pode utilizar a função auxiliar [reverse](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html), assim vai obter o índice da ultima ocorrência do caractere ":" e pode recortar a string desejada, utilizando a mesma lógica acima.

Segue um exemplo:

```
 id |              observacao            |
 ---+------------------------------------+---
  1 | Usuario: destino: NOME DO USUÁRIO
```

SQL:

```
 SELECT id, observacao, substring(observacao, position(':' in reverse(observacao))+1) AS recorte FROM <nome-da-tabela>;
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo, foi de grande ajuda.